# Python oop question

Tags: python

How do I call method `.get_item(Example1()).do_something()` in class `Base` from inside the class `Example2`?

```
class Base:

    items = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def get_item(self, item):
        return self.items[0]

class Item:
    pass

class Example1(Item):

    def do_something(self):
        print('do_something()')

class Example2(Item):

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        How call this method .get_item(Example1()).do_something() ?
        '''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    base = Base()
    base.add_item(Example1())
    base.add_item(Example2())
```

Comment: Are you trying to call another method in the `__init__` of Example2 or are you trying to call the `__init__` method itself? Actually I can't understand what you are asking. Please provide more information.

Comment: I wan't from Example1() or Example2() have access to methods from Base() class.

Comment: @vladislav godorin With two "from" in it, your sentence means nothing. Don't you read what you writed before posting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want such functionality, you need to pass `Base` to `Example2` guy:

```
class Example2(Item):

    def __init__(self, base):
         self.base = base
         self.base.get_item(Example1()).do_something()

         # or if don't want to store base, and just call its method once:
         base.get_item(Example1()).do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    base = Base()
    base.add_item(Example1())
    base.add_item(Example2(), base)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.get_item(...)
```

or

```
Base.get_item(self, ...)
```